# Gatsby Build Error on Netlify - page-data.json failed paged “/”

Tags: build, gatsby, netlify, emotion

when I try to build a gatsby app on netlify, I'm having this error that is generated by a 3rd party module called react-water-wave.
This is the error

[image: Netlify Deploy log]

I've already implemented a null loader on gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {


if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-water-wave/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

This is how is coded the gatsby-plugin-emotion on gatsby-config.js

```
plugins: [

{resolve: `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
  options: {
    // Accepts the following options, all of which are defined by `@emotion/babel-plugin` plugin.
    // The values for each key in this example are the defaults the plugin uses.
    sourceMap: true,
    autoLabel: "always",
    labelFormat: `[local]`,
    cssPropOptimization: true,
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-water-wave` seems to be discontinued, the last commit is from 3 years ago and it has been reported with some incompatibilities during SSR and React version as it is inferred from https://github.com/homerchen19/react-water-wave/issues/14 and https://github.com/homerchen19/react-water-wave/issues/27.

It seems to don't work with React versions greater than 17.

That said, try playing (downgrading) with React-core versions (which can potentially lead to other errors) or try finding another alternative.

Comment: Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To be honest I’ve ride away from npm react-wave package because I have not been able to compile the error. Have a nice day